# Как организовать чтение из файла по нажатию Button?

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток.

Начинаю осваивать самостоятельно Visual C++ 2010 Studio. Стоит задача написать универсальную программу-тест, которая берет данные из текстового файла, открываемого диалоговым окном. Пока я остановился на том, что если прописывать код посимвольного считывания из файла в главном файле проекта, то вроде все хорошо.  Что-то вроде

```
ifstream infile("D:\TEST.txt");

while (infile) {
    infile.get(ch);
    String ^ str1 = gcnew String(ch);
    str1 += ch;
}

textBox1->Text = str1;
```

Пробовал и другие способы, за исключением MFC - работает... Однако мне нужно запускать функцию чтения из файла и обработку символов нажатием кнопки "Button". Как это сделать?
Если я использую Ifstream в

```
private:System::Void button3_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e)
{
}
```

компилятор начинает сильно ругаться... Объясните, пожалуйста, гугл уже не спасает.

Да и вообще говорит, что ifstream: не является членом "std" если прописываю

```
std::ifstream infile("D:\TEST.txt");
```

С каких пор-то не является?

Comment: А пространство имен по умолчанию включено?

Comment: Да. прописал using namespace std;   в главном файле, потом попробовал то же прописать в Form1.h
Все равно не находит.

Answer (score 1):

[Практическое руководство. Чтение из текстового файла (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y52yxde8.aspx).

Пример:

```
try {
    StreamReader^ sr = File::OpenText(filename);

    String^ line;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((line = sr->ReadLine()) != nullptr) {
        amount++;
        // TODO:
    }
}
catch (Exception^ e) {
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Такой вариант подходит. Сейчас покопаюсь в этом направлении...
Но , если не трудно, объясните причину, почему не удается привязать пространство имен std?
Теперь искать как перекодировать строки, написанные кириллицей и как организовать теперь текстовый файл... Планировал организовать посимвольное считывание текста, первый символ забивать в переменную как правильный вариант ответа, а вопрос и текст вариантов ответа разделять метками, т.е. работать не со строковыми массивами, а напрямую с потоком символов. Или это считается моветоном?)

Comment: Каким методом для данного решения организовать вывод в TextBox из текстового файла кириллицы? SetLocale()?? Пробовал несколько вариантов типа 
#include <locale.h>
.............
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian");

нет эффекта
Блин..такой вопрос нубский.. самому стыдно( но подскажите если не сложно.

Comment: Нашел ответ) может кому будет полезно:
StreamReader^ sr = gcnew StreamReader("D:\\TEST.txt",System::Text::Encoding::Default);
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Т.е. по умолчанию используется кодировка UTF-8..Дефолт-Получает кодировку для текущей кодовой страницы ANSI операционной системы.

Comment: Теперь нужно организовать посмивольный анализ текста из файла..В библиотеках закопался......подскажите, кто может
Вот такой вариант нашел... 

   //Read 100 bytes into an array from the specified file.
        int nBytes=100;
        byte[] ByteArray=new byte[nBytes];
        int nBytesRead=fs.Read(ByteArray, 0, nBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes have been read from the specified file.", nBytesRead.ToString());
    }
}
если вместо nBytes поставить 1. будет читаться 1 символ?) сейчас нет возможности попробовать ...