# Чтение данных из текстового файла

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Здравствуйте.

Объясните пожалуйста, как можно организовать чтение из файла, допустим, путем

```
StreamReader("D:\\TEST.txt",System::Text::Encoding::Default);
```

только чтобы "`D:\\TEST.txt`" выбиралось из диалогового окна. Если возможно, то на любом простейшем примере.

Заранее спасибо. С уважением, Евгений.

Answer (score 2):

```
  OpenFileDialog^ ofd = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
  if (ofd->ShowDialog() == ::DialogResult::OK)
  {
       String^ filename = ofd->FileName;
       // TODO: Читать из файла
  }
```

Про собственно чтение из файла средствами C++/CLI смотрите в этом ответе: [Как организовать чтение из файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/85902/) Работа на запись осуществляется аналогично.

Comment: Компилятор ругается, что DialogResult: символ слева от "::" должен представлять тип